# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION using UIButton

Tags: swift, button

in my apps i use storyboard and directly programmatically at the same time.
On a view i want to go to another view using a programmatically UIButton
Here's the code

```
  func QuitView(sender:UIButton){
    self.presentViewController(FirstViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And the error is:

> Thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0) error

Comment: An [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) would help to identify the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild shot in the dark, but it looks like you're trying to return to the first view controller, so do `self.dismissViewController(animated: true)`